# Translation invariant metrics and topological groups

Tags: metric-spaces, topological-groups

During a lecture was pointed out that one of the main feature, from a topological perspective, of normed vector spaces is the translational invariance, that is that one can study the topological structure about a fixed point and then move the open balls wherever needed.

However such a property can be stated for a simpler space than a vector space. A group $(G,\cdot)$ with a distance $d$ such that $d(x,y)=d(xy^{-1},e)$ where $e$ is the identity element should be sufficient (can be easily seen that $d(x,y)=d(xz^{-1},yz^{-1})$ follows and vice versa).

Now I wonder if

1. is $(G,\cdot)$ a topological group?
2. is $(G,d)$ complete if and only if all the *absolute* convergent series (with respect to $\rVert x \lVert = d (x,e)$ which obviously isn't a norm) are convergent?

I think that commutativity is sufficient (i.e. $(G,\cdot)$ an Abelian group) for the first point, is it also necessary?

Comment: I don't understand "2." How an "absolute" convergent series in a metric space can be non-convergent?

Comment: @AlexRavsky For example consider the series $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$, provided with the usual sum and the metric $d(x,y)=\lvert x-y \rvert \in \mathbb{R}$. This series doesn't converge, but the _absolute_ series does.

Comment: You mean by an *absolutely* convergent sequence a sequence $\{x_n\}$ such that the series $\sum d(x_n, x_{n+1})$ converges? If I remember it right, a metric space is complete if each Cauchy sequence of its points converges.  (A sequence $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy, if for each $\varepsilon>0$ exists a natural number $n_0$ such that for each natural numbers $n,n'>n_0$ we have $d(x_n, x_{n'})<\varepsilon$). The triangle inequality should imply that each absolutely convergent sequence is Cauchy.

Comment: From the other side, a sequence $\{e_n/\sqrt{n}\}$ (where $e_n$ are the standard orts of Hilbert space $\ell^2$) should be Cauchy, but not *absolutely* convergent. Nevertheless, the Hilbert space $\ell^2$ should be complete. But may be there are incomplete abelian topological groups topologized by an invariant metric in which each absolutely convergent sequence converges. I’ll think about it.

Comment: It seems the following. Property (2) holds even for metric spaces. Indeed, let $(X, d)$ be a metric space in which each absolutely convergent sequence converges. Let $\{x_n\}$ be a Cauchy sequence of points of the space $X$. Let $(\hat X,\hat d)$ be a completion of the space $(X, d)$. Then the sequence $\{x_n\}$ has a limit point $x’\in \hat X$. Since $X$ is a dense subset of the space $\hat X$, there exists a sequence $\{x’_n\}$ of points of the space of $X$ such that $\hat d(x’, x’_n)< 2^{-n}$.

Comment: Then the sequence $\{x’_n\}$ is absolutely convergent. Therefore it has a limit $x\in\hat X$. But $x$ is also a limit of the sequence $\{x’_n\}$. Therefore $x’=x\in X$, and the sequence $\{x_n\}$ converges in $X$. Thus the metric space $(X,d)$ is complete.

Comment: For _absolute_ convergence of a series $\sum x_n $ I mean that the series $\sum \lVert x_n \rVert$ converges (and I use the italics because $\rVert \lVert$ isn't a norm, indeed there isn't even a vector space). The statement that all absolute convergent series converges is a characterization of Banach spaces (i.e. complete normed vector spaces). My two question were indeed suggested by analogy with those spaces (Banach spaces are topological vector spaces too).

Answer (score 2):

It seems the following.

Let $G$ be a group which topology is determined by a *two-side* invariant metric $d$, that is $d(x,y)=d(zxt, zyt)$ for all $x,y,z,t\in G$. Then $G$ is topological group because the inversion and the multiplication on the $G$ are continuous. Indeed, let $x,y,x’,y'\in G$,  $\varepsilon>0$, $d(x,x’)< \varepsilon$, and $d(x,x’)< \varepsilon$. Then $d(x’^{-1}, x^{-1})=d(x’^{-1}x, e)=d(x, x’)< \varepsilon $ and $d(x’y’,xy)\le d(x’y’,x’y)+d(x’y,xy)=d(y’,y)+d(x’,x)<2\varepsilon$. From the other side, I expect that there is a non-abelian group $G$ which topology is determined by a *right* invariant metric $d$ (that is $d(x,y)=d(xt, yt)$ for all $x,y,t\in G$) which is not a topological group.